# Python ONVIF Camera

Tags: python, python-onvif

I'm trying to use Python ONVIF to control PTZ camera, I checked some examples from [github](https://github.com/smartsenselab/sensecam-control/blob/master/example_control_onvif.py) and configured them into my camera IP address.
This is the example that I use:

```
import cv2
import sys
import threading
from sensecam_control import onvif_control


ip = '192.168.150.155'
login = 'admin'
password = '123456'

exit_program = 0


def event_keyboard(k):
    global exit_program

    if k == 27:  # esc
        exit_program = 1

    elif k == ord('w') or k == ord('W'):
        X.relative_move(0, 0.1, 0)

    elif k == ord('a') or k == ord('A'):
        X.relative_move(-0.1, 0, 0)

    elif k == ord('s') or k == ord('S'):
        X.relative_move(0, -0.1, 0)

    elif k == ord('d') or k == ord('D'):
        X.relative_move(0.1, 0, 0)

    elif k == ord('h') or k == ord('H'):
        X.go_home_position()

    elif k == ord('z') or k == ord('Z'):
        X.relative_move(0, 0, 0.05)

    elif k == ord('x') or k == ord('X'):
        X.relative_move(0, 0, -0.05)


def capture(ip_camera):
    global exit_program

    #url http login axis camera
    #ip2 = 'http://' + login + ':' + password + '@' + ip_camera + '/mjpg/1/video.mjpg?'

    #url rtsp axis camera
    ip2 = 'rtsp://192.168.150.155:554' + login + ':' + password + '@' + ip_camera + '/axis-media/media.amp'

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ip2)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret is not False:
            break

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if exit_program == 1:
            sys.exit()

        #cv2.namedWindow('Camera', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('Camera', frame)
        event_keyboard(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff)


X = onvif_control.CameraControl(ip, login, password)
X.camera_start()

t = threading.Thread(target=capture, args=(ip,))
t.start()
```

I can't run this code in superuser mode, it says:

> [rtsp @ 0x7f5638008220] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Stream Not Found

If not using superuser mode, the error says:

> onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: (401, 'Unauthorized')

Comment: now i can stream it, this is because the rtsp that i use is wrong. When i change the format of rtsp link like this
```ip2 = 'rtsp://192.168.150.155:554'``` it works

Comment: But, the real problem is, i still can't move my camera with the order from my keyboard. All the orders like move up, down, etc. doesn't work. Except, orders for quit the program, it's actually work...

Comment: Did you solved the problem of moving the camera?